# Can i use two different user tables for on WP install?

Tags: users

I like to make a difference between internal use of our WP website and extern by
using an seperate users table and usermeta table, i tried this but it doesn't work

```
if($_POST['user_login']!='admin-username') {//or $ip != xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'wp_users_extern');
define('CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', 'wp_usermeta_extern');
}
```

How can i make it working?
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not going to work because you won't always have the post value on each page (only when they have just logged in).
So as soon as wp serves up the next page it won't have a the POST variable anymore.

Why do you feel a need to do this? (Personally I cannot think of a good reason)

If they need different capabilties, then 
You could simply create additional roles

If it is simply for reporting, then categorise users in some other way with a custom meta field.

Comment: Hi anmari, i like to use WP for registeration and use wp functions to make a custom exhibitors enviroment, which has no publish roles. Just an order system. I don't want the exhibitors to be an user of the main site. And i like to have a strict difference between internal personel and exhibitors. 
Hope you understand my case and maybe you have some great tips .Regards Barry

Comment: Hi Barry, As far as I am aware there is NO way to have different user tables since you need a user table first to decide which kind of user the user is. IE: wp, before it knows anything about the user, has to look the user up somewhere so that it can tell what kind of user it is and only then can it 'do' something different. The different 'doing' is managed by the wordpress capabilties.                                   The only other way would be to have two wordpress installs - one for the main site and one for the ordering system.

Comment: It sounds like your exhibitors could be 'subscribers'. This is the lowest default wp role with only read access and possibly comments if you allow that. Using a role/capability plugin you could create an even lesser role (called exhibitor perhaps) that cannot even comment. They certainly do not have 'publish' rights. Read more here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Perhaps it would help you if you thought of the 'roles' as different sections of the table - almost like different tables. They appear in different tabs on the user list.

Comment: hi anmari, tx i am testing with a custom role "exhibitor" and a custom post type exhibitors_wishes. But i am a bit stuck in my thoughts. Is it possible to have a CPT per logged in user, i mean only exhibitor A can see their own CPT and not the others?

Or should i kill the single WP setup and go for a MU WP setup, which is new to me?

Comment: what is on their 'page' ? why would a normal private profile page with added fields etc not be adequate? why a custom post type ? why not just a page ?   CPT's should only be used when there is special functionality/template invloved (eg events pages). Even then 1 custom post Type would do it. If they edit the CPT pages then they get heir own page of that CPT. If not, if just displaying fields, then one page with coding behind it.

Only use wp ms system if they needed to create multiple pages themselves that were public. Going ms one would still have theprofile/page/cpt/privacy questions.